# Undesired jitter in pgfplots when consecutive values are close

Tags: pgfplots

I need to plot data where some of the consecutive coordinates are very close to each other. There seems to be something weird jitter appearing when this is done using thick lines, as may be seen in the figure below.[image: jitter on thick line, less jitter on thin line]

What can I do to get rid of this annoying jitter while still using a thick line style? I would prefer doing this without cleaning the data file before it is presented to pfgplots.

The code for generating this plot is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,compat/show suggested version=false}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{line.dat}
y               x
0.030253        -0.074843
0.057078        -0.075733
0.072498        -0.036123
0.074581        -0.047017
0.058578        -0.062860
0.050274        -0.119600
0.056557        -0.075105
0.070009        -0.108146
0.050349        -0.076270
0.095860        -0.047266
0.071306        -0.068749
0.084431        -0.072772
0.108305        -0.115240
0.112039        -0.099893
0.108454        -0.082722
0.088435        -0.096626
0.113089        -0.151948
0.171604        -0.164238
0.147025        -0.136150
0.170872        -0.134639
0.187245        -0.152217
0.147094        -0.124690
0.188067        -0.129349
0.206525        -0.127766
0.194892        -0.109653
0.213251        -0.150639
0.228910        -0.115494
0.270712        -0.092827
0.277597        -0.078565
-8.361062       84.157746
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{line.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x tick label as interval=false,axis equal]
\addplot[blue,ultra thick] table[x=x,y=y] {line.dat};
\addplot[red] table[x=x,y expr={\thisrow{y}+4}] {line.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=40mm]{line.tikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284389/2552

Comment: @Jake: Thank you! The solution mentioned there, to add `/tikz/line join=bevel` to the axis options, worked nicely.